# Remove photo padding in moderncv classic

Tags: spacing, moderncv

When `\photo` is used in moderncv, it includes a `~3px` padding between the image and the border.  How does one remove this?  I have found the part of the [`moderncvstyleclassic.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstyleclassic.sty) that deals with the photo (line 160), but don't know how to change it.  I'd also like to know how to change the colour of the border, or even remove it entirely.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's also very important to add you version of `moderncv`. In the last weeks there are many updates.

Comment: The current macro `\photo` has two options, one for the photo size, one for the thickness of the border. To remove the border use `0pt`.

Comment: Guess I'm using an old version of moderncv then T_T

Comment: I believe the answer by @nathdwek is more accurate. That removed the white padding between the border and the image using `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` instead of removing the entire border with the other option

Answer (score 4):

To remove the border for the border just use a current version of `moderncv` and try the following MWE (just to show you how a MWE could be for your case).  In line 21 you have the border activated, in the commented line 22 the border is deactivated. Just move the comment sign `%`.

The macro `\photo[width photo][border thickness]{name of photo}` does for you what you want.

Please note that I used a picture from package [`MWE`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe), that should be installed on your computer but must not be loaded to use the included pictures.

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113566/remove-photo-padding-in-moderncv-classic
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}  % change the width of the column with the dates
\setlength{\footskip}{37pt} % defines space for footer

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}% optional, ...
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          % optional, ...
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           % optional, ...
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                             % optional, ...
\email{john@doe.org}                               % optional, ...
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, ...
\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, ...
 \photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}              % Photo with border with 0.4pt thickness
%\photo[64pt][0pt]{example-image-a}                % Photo without border 
\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, ...

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
% your datas ...

\end{document} %===== File mwe-mcv.tex =====
```

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer covered how to remove the border altogether around the photo in moderncv, using the syntax provided by this package. Here I'm going to show you how to remove the padding, which was initially asked and is a little bit less immediate (using moderncv 1.5.1).

moderncv uses a `\framebox{}` to get a border around your photo. As shown in [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#framebox), the only way to modify the padding is through the `\fboxsep` variable. Knowing that you can use the command `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` somewhere before the `\photo` command in order to remove the padding (be it preambule or near the photo declaration, or even in the package itself, depending on how it makes most sense to you)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{moderncv}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{red}

%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Don Knuth Street, 42}{Tex City}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\photo[64pt][0.8pt]{placeholder.png}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To complete what has already been said and answer the second part of the question, if you want to change the color of the border, you can do this :

`\renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{\lightgray}{white}}`

To be placed before the command `\photo`. This will set the borders to lightgray and the background to white. Note that this should change the border colors of any element using `fbox`, so it may not be optimal.

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446556/203822