# How to change the default border color of fbox?

Tags: color, fbox

I have a lot of figures inside an fbox. Unfortunately the default black is too strong for my advisor and I need to change the default border color to something more soft.

I've done my research and so far all other answers suggest do solve the problem by [not using fbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46408/change-border-color-of-fbox) and switching to other packages. That's something I'd like to avoid, unless absolutely necessary.

Surely there is an option for something so basic in the fbox package itself?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by "fbox package"?

Comment: fbox is not a package but a simple command. You could redefine it, but this would affect all uses of fbox.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How would one do so?

Comment: @BambOo I specifically linked to that post already and commented that it is **not** what I want.

Comment: It is not beacause some things that you saw there are not what you want that every piece of information from this post isn't relevant for you or anyone else. If you look deeper into details, the linked post has been deemed a duplicate of a previous one where a solution using only
the `color` package was proposed as `\newcommand{\myfbox}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\fbox{\normalcolor#2}}}`. By the way we cannot say what packages are allowed or not if you do not give us a list

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this. It will also set the background to white, normally this should be not a problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand\fbox{\fcolorbox{red}{white}}
\begin{document}

\fbox{text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To me, this is a good answer, so +1, but looking at the OP's comments, he/she probably won't see it that way.

Comment: This is exactly what I want: a way to set the "default border color of fbox". I understand that maybe my terminology was wrong due to being a latex novice, but this user seemed to be able to see through that. I'm sure the ever flowing visitors from Google will agree with me that it is a relevant problem that has not been answered as desired by most before, and will be happy to see this answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Without setting the background color, one can save the current text color and apply it when the text of the `\fbox` is typeset, changing color for typesetting the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\cfbox\fbox
\let\c@frameb@x\@frameb@x
\pretocmd{\cfbox}
  {\leavevmode\begingroup\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}\color{red}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\cfbox{\@frameb@x}{\c@frameb@x}{}{}
\patchcmd{\c@frameb@x}
  {\box\@tempboxa}
  {\color{currentcolor}\box\@tempboxa}
  {}{}
\apptocmd{\c@frameb@x}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text \cfbox{text} text

\fcolorbox{green}{blue}{text \cfbox{text} text}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer a different command to redefining `\fbox`. If you instead want to use `\fbox`, just remove the `\let\cfbox\fbox` line and change `\cfbox` into `\fbox` in the remaining places.

[image]